A question about the norm of ordinal functions
I've asked this question on mse but it seems like it's not such a trivial question. I hope asking again here won't break any rules...
Let $\kappa$ be an uncountable regular cardinal and $I$ an ideal on it, we can define a strict partial order $<_I$ and a preorder $\leq_I$ on functions from $\kappa$ to $\mathbf{Ord}$ by setting $f<_I g\Leftrightarrow \{\xi\in\kappa\mid f(\xi)\geq g(\xi)\}\in I$ and $f\leq_I g\Leftrightarrow \{\xi\in\kappa\mid f(\xi)>g(\xi)\}\in I$. Moreover, if $<_I$ is well-founded, we can define a norm function by transfinite induction using $\|f\|_I=\operatorname{sup}\{\|g\|_I+1\mid g<_I f\}$. Suppose $<_I$ is well-founded from now on.
Consider a $<_I-$increasing sequence $\langle f_\alpha\rangle_{\alpha\in\theta}$ where $\theta$ is a limit ordinal, we say $h$ is an upper bound of this sequence if $f_\alpha<_I h$ for all $\alpha\in\theta$, a least upper bound if it is an upper bound and for any other upper bound $g$ we have $f\leq_I g$, an exact upper bound if it is a least upper bound and for every $g<_I h$ there's $\alpha\in\theta$ making $g\leq_I f_\alpha$. It's easy to verify that if h is an exact upper bound then $\|h\|_I=\operatorname{sup}\{\|f_\alpha\|_I\mid\alpha\in\theta\}$, but I wonder if the converse is true. Precisely, my questions are:

Suppose $h$ is an upper bound satisfying $\|h\|_I=\operatorname{sup}\{\|f_\alpha\|_I\mid\alpha\in\theta\}$, can we conclude that $h$ is an exact upper bound, or at least $h$ is a least upper bound?

If $g<_I f$ and $\|g\|_I=\beta<\gamma=\|f\|_I$, is there always an $h$ for every ordinal $\delta$ between $\beta$ and $\gamma$ so that $\|h\|_I=\delta$ and $g<_I h<_I f$?



M.SE: A question about the norm of ordinal functions
